# Can I VBA for conditional loop to look for traffic light icons on a table that was conditionally formatted

Tags: vba

I have a table that is already conditionally formatted based some values with traffic light icon

[image]

Basically I want loop to check the following:

1. if Traffic light is green of a current month, check= N
2. if traffic light is Yellow, Check = Y
3. if traffic light is red, check is Y
4. if it's empty, check is N
5. if previous month light are red or yellow, check = Y
6. if it's empty, check = N

Here are what I have so far, but the traffic light condition wouldn't work:

D

```
im locate_month As Range
Dim lastmonth As Range
Dim lastquarter As Range
Dim previousmonth As String
Dim Frequency As Range

Dim lrow As Integer
Dim row As Integer

Dim Check As Range

Dim currentmonth1 As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Current KIs")

currentmonth1 = Sheets("Instruction").Range("B6").Value
previousmonth = Sheets("Instruction").Range("B7").Value
previousquarter = Sheets("Instruction").Range("B9").Value
With ws.Range("3:3")
    Set locate_month = .Find(currentmonth1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set lastmonth = .Find(previousmonth, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set lastquarter = .Find(previouquarter, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set Frequency = .Find("Frequency", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set Check = .Find("Check (Y/N)", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

col = locate_month.Column


' start the loop based on condition'

'find the last row of the data set
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

'loop through all rows
For row = 4 To lrow
    'Check for month values
    If UCase(ws.Cells(row, "B").Value) = "M" Then
        If ws.Cells(row, locate_month.Column) = "" Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "N"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, locate_month.Column) = "N/A" Or "n/a" Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "N"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, locate_month.Column).FormatCondition(1).Icon = xlIconGreenTrafficLight Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "N"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, locate_month.Column) = "G" Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "N"
        Else
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "Y"
        End If
        'Check previouse month value for change in color
        If ws.Cells(row, lastmonth.Column).FormatCondition(1).Icon = xlIconYellowTrafficLight Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "Y"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, lastmonth.Column).FormatCondition(1).Icon = xlIconRedTrafficLight Then
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "Y"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, lastmonth.Column) = "R" Then
         ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "Y"
        Else
            ws.Cells(row, Check.Column) = "Y"
         
        End If
   
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with `wouldn't work`?

Comment: The icon property comes from `FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(1).Icon` There's no `Icon` member in `FormatCondition`

Comment: Which are the rules which determine the traffic light color? You should check (only) these rules, not the traffic light themselves on the checked cell.

Comment: So does it mean it's not feasible to check what are the cells conditionally formatted to? ( except cell colour but not the conditional format) at VBA?

Comment: I updated it to : 
        ElseIf ws.Cells(row, locate_month.Column).FormatCondition(1).IconCriteria(3).Icon = xlIconGreenTrafficLight, it's still not recognizing the traffic light and return to "Y" or "N" at the check column where I designed.